# Overflow after using "FillSampleValues()" in Teechart(VC++6.0,Teechart8.ocx environment)

Tags: overflow, teechart

I'm a very beginner of TeeChart.

When I add a member variable called m_chart for the chart，it looks okay.

Then I add "m_chart.Series(0).FillSampleValues(50);" in CMy312Dlg::OnInitDialog()......

and overflow ocurred.

What's wrong? 
So sad to find that I don't describe my question well.(Well I'm a freshman on StackOverflow,and cannot add image for my poor reputation.)

But if you need more details,I will try to describe for you.:)

Comment: Please post the relevant section of code, as well as the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding data to a series you must create this series and add it to the chart to access it the way you do. You'll find examples at the Visual C++ sections in the tutorials and examples folders. If the problem persists please [send us](http://www.steema.net/upload/) an example project we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here.

Comment: Yes, I'd added  Series0. Thanks for your answer.I will try to download TeeChart from steema.com(I downloaded single file,"TeeChart8.ocx"from csdn.net) and install it so that  examples folders are available.Or I will go to teechart.net.If I still don't work out it,I will send my project to you.Thank you very much.